# Problems with installing packages with Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I tried installing `pandas_datareader` in Anaconda using `conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader`. It gives me this result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywin32_bootstrap'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 7 of C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywin32.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywin32_bootstrap'

Remainder of file ignored
```

Okay, bad luck I thought, and I tried installing something else (plotly). And this gave me exactly the same result.

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
conda remove [-c anaconda] pywin32
conda install -c anaconda pywin32
```

Code in brakets is not necessary.

This should reinstall pywin32. And go for another try. It worked for me using pip.